# App Angular 2, decrease request in production mode

Tags: angular, gulp

I am developing an application in Angular 2, I need to put it into production, but the loading time is very high, and it performs 243 request.
[image]
Is it possible to reduce the amount of request? How to do?

This is index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">

  <link href="libs/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="libs/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="libs/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'es', includedLanguages: 'ar,de,el,en,es,fr,hi,it,ja,pt,ru,zh-CN', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>


  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
    <my-app><div class="loading-center"><span>Cargando</span></div></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a system.conf.js file

```
var isPublic = typeof window != "undefined";

(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',       
    '@angular':                   (isPublic)? '@angular' : 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       (isPublic)? 'rxjs' : 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-jwt':               '../libs/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
    'primeng':                    '../libs/primeng'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {    
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-jwt':               { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'primeng':                    { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.min.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-express-mongo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Angular2, Mongo, Gulp, Typescript and Express",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "compile": "gulp compile",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "deploy": "concurrently --kill-others \"gulp watch\" \"gulp start\"",
    "postinstall": "gulp installTypings"
  },

  "keywords": [
    "Angular2",
    "Express",
    "Quick Start",
    "Gulp",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Santiago",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.15",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.22",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^2.7.0",
    "primeng": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",
    "concurrently": "^2.1.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.3",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "gulp-typings": "^2.0.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-node": "1.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp"),
    del = require("del"),
    tsc = require("gulp-typescript"),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json"),
    tslint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    gulpTypings = require("gulp-typings");

/**
 * Remove build directory.
 */
gulp.task('clean', (cb) => {
    return del(["dist"], cb);
});

/**
 * Build Express server
 */
gulp.task('build:server', function () {
    var tsProject = tsc.createProject('server/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src('server/src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/server'))
});

gulp.task('build:client', function () {
    var tsProject = tsc.createProject('client/tsconfig.json');
    var tsResult = gulp.src('client/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject))
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/client'))
});

/**
 * Lint all custom TypeScript files.
 */
gulp.task('tslint', () => {
    return gulp.src("client/app/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(tslint())
        .pipe(tslint.report('prose'));
});


/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", ["tslint"], () => {
    let tsResult = gulp.src("client/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/client"));
});

/**
 * Copy all resources that are not TypeScript files into build directory. e.g. index.html, css, images
 */
gulp.task("clientResources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["client/**/*", "!**/*.ts", "!client/typings", "!client/typings/**", "!client/*.json"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/client"));
});

/**
 * Copy bin directory for www
 */
gulp.task("serverResources", () => {
    return gulp.src(["server/src/bin/**"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/server/bin"));
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'core-js/client/**',
        'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map',
        'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'font-awesome/css',
        'font-awesome/fonts',
        'angular2-jwt/**',
        'primeng/**'

    ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/client/libs"));
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("css", () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'bootstrap/dist/**/**'
    ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/client/css"));
});


/**
 * Install typings for server and client.
 */
gulp.task("installTypings", function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(["./server/typings.json", "./client/typings.json"])
        .pipe(gulpTypings(null)); //will install all typingsfiles in pipeline.
    return stream; // by returning stream gulp can listen to events from the stream and knows when it is finished.
});

/**
 * Start the express server with nodemon
 */
gulp.task('start', function () {
    nodemon({
        script: 'dist/server/bin/www'
        , ext: 'html js'
        , ignore: ['ignored.js']
        , tasks: ['tslint']
    })
        .on('restart', function () {
            console.log('restarted!')
        });
});

/**
 * Build the project.
 * 1. Clean the build directory
 * 2. Build Express server
 * 3. Build the Angular app
 * 4. Copy the resources
 * 5. Copy the dependencies.
 */

gulp.task("build", function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean', 'build:server', 'build:client', 'clientResources', 'serverResources', 'libs', 'css', callback);
});

/**
 * Watch for changes in TypeScript, HTML and CSS files.
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(["client/**/*.ts"], ['compile']).on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('TypeScript file ' + e.path + ' has been changed. Compiling.');
    });

    gulp.watch(["client/**/*.html", "client/**/*.css"], ['clientResources']).on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('Resource file ' + e.path + ' has been changed. Updating.');
    });

    gulp.watch(["server/src/**/*.ts"], ['compile']).on('change', function (e) {
        console.log('TypeScript file ' + e.path + ' has been changed. Compiling.');
    });
});

/**
 * Build the project.
 * 1. Clean the build directory
 * 2. Build Express server
 * 3. Build the Angular app
 * 4. Copy the resources
 * 5. Copy the dependencies.
 */

gulp.task("build", function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean', 'build:server', 'build:client', 'clientResources', 'serverResources', 'libs', 'css', callback);
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    runSequence('build:server', 'build:client', 'clientResources', 'serverResources', 'libs', 'css', 'watch', 'start');
});
```